# int* = int ? Different levels of indirection

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

Why does the last line of this segment compile and run in C (Visual Studio)?  It is `int*` on the left and `int` on the right. The types do not match so I would think it is an error.  In other words a data value should not be compatible with a memory address.

```
    int x = 6;
    int* baz = &x;
    int* foo = &x;


    foo = baz;     /* ok */
    foo = *baz;   /* ?? */
```

I assumed it would not compile.

Comment: at hardware level - memory address is number, and quite often has the same bit width as int, this is why c allows such things, but it should usually issue warning

Comment: Turn up the warning level on your compiler. You should see something like _"assignment makes pointer from int"_

Comment: C allows you to shoot yourself in the foot, and hands you the ammo with which to do it. Turn up the hints and warnings for your compiler.

Comment: See also https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565

Comment: Heed thy warnings.

Answer (score 1):

[MSVC does give a warning for this.](https://godbolt.org/z/3jj493354) You must be ignoring the warning.

Elevate warnings to errors by using the `/WX` switch.

The C standard requires a diagnostic message for this because it violates the constraint for simple assignment in C 2018 6.5.16 1:

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> [list of six cases, none of which covers assigning an `int` value to a pointer]

However, even a compiler that conforms to the C standard is allowed to accept the program even after issuing a diagnostic for a constraint violation,<sup>1</sup> and that is what happened. Using `/WX` will prevent that.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> It is allowed to do this because there is no rule against it in the standard, and footnote 9 says:

> … It [a C implementation] can also successfully translate an invalid program…

Comment: Interesting. I thought C permits this (as opposed to C++) because nobody dared to invalidate such code. Is there a reason beyond backwards compatibility that all compilers compile this as C but not as C++? Interestingly, the "shall" is in a constraint section, so the program does not have undefined behavior (4./2), IIUC.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: The program does have undefined behavior. When a program violates a rule in a constraints section, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a memory address as an integer. Doing `foo = *baz` is the same as doing `foo = 6`.

In other words, your integer pointer `foo` is now pointing to memory at address `0x6`. This still compiles, but if you try to dereference `foo`, you'll encounter undefined behavior.

Comment: I fixed an important typo in your answer, but fundamentally you didn't answer why the compiler lets this through without an explicit cast.